# MySql select max value of a pair of column in one query

Tags: mysql, max

I need a query to select a row based on a max pair of columns. In the following table, how would you select the rows which has the highest VALUE1 and in this first results set, the one which has the highest VALUE2?

```
+----+---------+---------+
| ID | VALUE1  | VALUE2  |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |       1 |       1 |
|  2 |       2 |       1 |
|  3 |       5 |       4 |
|  4 |       4 |       1 |
|  5 |       4 |       3 |
|  6 |       4 |       5 |
|  7 |       5 |       1 |
|  8 |       4 |       2 |
|  9 |       4 |       6 |
| 10 |       4 |       8 |
| 11 |       5 |       3 |
```

In this case, the row with ID = 3 should be returned.

Comment: wot hav u tryed? For instance have you tried anything with ORDER BY and LIMIT?

Comment: Actually I have not tryed anything. I was thinking about something with SELECT MAX(VALUE1), MAX(VALUE2)...but I don't think it will work. I've thought about ORDER BY/GROUP BY but I wondered if I could get a single result.

Comment: Row 3 should be returned because in the rows that have the max value for VALUE1 it is the one that has the max value for VALUE2. I want to get a single result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY Value1 DESC, Value2 DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This works. I thought that there would be a solution without using LIMIT. If not I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Limit is the best option here but if you still want some other method then you can use sub query

```
SELECT * FROM tableName  where (Value1 + Value2) = (select max((Value1 + Value2))
from tableName)
```

Comment: Will not work, as it will get (4,8) instead of (5,4)